# AngularJS 1.x Multiple named and nested views needles refreshing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm trying to create a multi-viewed page with states, and when changing the url (for example: studentDetails) only a single view changes and the others stay the same.

I almost made it, but when going to another URL, the views I don't declare about or pass empty objects to just don't show.
This is what I have so far (via plunker): http://plnkr.co/edit/FaVaTMaCZnj3beEaamcL

Here is my app config:

```
app.config( ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state("studentParent", {
        url: "/students",
        controller: "main",
        templateUrl: "templates/mainview.htm"
    })
    .state("studentDrillDown", {
      url: "/studentsDd",
      controller: "main",
      templateUrl: "templates/dd.htm"
    })
    .state("studentParent.students", {
        url: "/",
        views: {
          view1: {
            controller: "main",
            templateUrl: "templates/students.htm",
          },
          view2: {
            controller: "main",
            templateUrl: "templates/students.htm",
          },
          view3: {
            controller: "main",
            templateUrl: "templates/students.htm",
          }
        }
    })
    .state("studentParent.studentDetails", {
        url: "/:id",
        views: {
          view1: {
            controller: "std",
            templateUrl: "templates/studentDetails.htm",
          },
          view2: {
            controller: "std",
            templateUrl: "templates/studentDetails.htm",
          },
          view3: {}
        }
    })
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Not understood what exactly do you need. :(

Comment: @AnkitVadi see the attached plunker, when I change my url, I need part of the views to change but others to stay in their current state, but if I don't declare the view in the "views" object it just makes the undeclared view disappear.

Comment: Sounds like you might need Sitcky States - https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky